# How to create a folder called "dimens" in Android Studio under Values folder?

Tags: android, android-studio

I am doing an Android Application for that i need to create a folder called "dimens".
How to create a folder called "dimens" in Android Studio under Values folder?

Comment: you can't. you can have a file called `dimens.xml` inside `values` tho

Comment: after created that is that possible?

Comment: you can't have folders inside `values` . Only files with extension `xml`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Blackbelt said, you can't have folders inside "values" folder, and therefore can't create "dimens" folder inside "values" folder.

You can only create dimens xml file for storing dimension values, and You create it in "values" folder.

I guess You are following some tutorial...if that's true, then it's probably typing mistake.

Answer (score 0):

I think the confusion is caused by the Android view in Android Studio which shows a folder dimens when you create one of the built in project templates, this is some sort of logical grouping and no folder actually exists on disk. Spend a good 15 mins trying to make the folder.
[image]